# Comparing impact of training data size - what testing data size?

Tags: classification, dataset, accuracy, train

I am training a classifier using BERT and want to check how the accuracy changes with increasing training data size. Up until now, I have 1k annotated training samples and tested the accuracy for different subsizes of this set (200, 400, 600, 800, 1000) and divided the training and test data with a 80:20 ratio.
The problem that occurred to me is that in my case I was always using different testing samples in order to assess the accuracy. However, if I understood correctly, the best approach would be to keep a constant test data set across all subsets of testing.
My question now:

Is this thinking correct?
If yes, would I then choose 20% of the whole dataset (e.g. 1000*0.2 = 200) for all 5 training sizes (200, 400, 600, 800, 1000) when reporting accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important things to consider here.

First, unless you have a very high signal-to-noise ratio, your sample size is too small for reliable use of split-sample validation. See [Frank Harrell's blog post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/) specifically on that subject, where he suggests that 20,000 or more cases are needed for that approach.

The classic train/test split does implicitly assume a single held-out test sample, so that you evaluate the performance of a particular model developed with a separate training (and perhaps validation) set. Otherwise, in an approach such as you describe, you are evaluating the performance of multiple models each trained on different sets. Even putting aside the small-sample problem, it's not clear what to report in that case. Which are you defining as the model to report?

Repeated cross-validation and bootstrapping provide better approaches to a data sample of 1000. Strictly, those methods evaluate the modeling process rather than the specific model. You report the model based on the entire sample, but estimate how well that type of modeling would work if you repeatedly applied it to new data samples.

Second, [accuracy is not a good measure of model performance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/28500). That's typically evaluated at a probability cutoff of 0.5 (often a hidden assumption of the software), which is only useful if you know that false positive and false negative classifications have the same costs. This site has many pages devoted to the inadequacies of accuracy and the superiority of [strictly proper scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule). Once you have a well calibrated probability model you can apply it more precisely for particular classification-cost tradeoffs.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem with accuracy as a measure for model performance. This problem is also amplified because my data set (three labels) is very sparse for one label in particular. I will look into scoring rules.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if you want to be sure the differences in accuracy are due only to the increase in the size of the training set, then use the same test data for each training size.

If you want more confidence in your result, then you could create multiple test sets (say 5 test sets of 20% of the data or 10 test sets of 10% of the data, as you would do for k-fold cross validation). For each test set, train models using all the training sizes. This would then give you 5 (or 10) estimates of the accuracy for each training size. The average of these should be a more reliable estimate than the result from a single model.

Comment: Thank you. As the other comment has pointed out, accuracy seems to be problematic as a measure in my case. Still, I will train the model again with 5-fold cross-validation using the max test set size for all training sizes and see what impact it has on my measure.